# how to extract time from datetime sql

Tags: sql, datetime

I have this datetime format on my table and I want to separate the date and time in separated column:

```
2021-01-16 08:55:50
```

I have tried:

```
select *,
   date(date_time) as event_date,
   time(date_time) as event_time
from table1;
```

It gave me an error saying:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "date_time"
  Position: 55
```

Comment: Please specify which sql dialect it is.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like postgres from the error number, but do please always tag your database name and version.

You can cast a datetime to date or time to get those portions:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  date_time::date as event_date,
  date_time::time as event_time
FROM t
```

Comment: In Postgres `date(date_time)` is pretty much the same as `date_time::date`